# Create a simple form in ActiveAdmin as a "register_page"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I basially want to create a form. On submission of that form I want to be writing to the different tables.

So my idea was to create a page using "register_page"

In that use

```
    form do |f|
        f.input name: "name", value: "-some value-", label: "Name"
        f.input type: :submit
    end
```

Now the problem is, this only displays the text field, I would like to be like how the other "new forms" are, with a label and to the right of that the textfield, which are associated to an activerecord model.

Questions:

- How can I have a "label and textfield" side by side
- How can I set the form to be "post" method
- How can I have the form to operate in a scope of a different object, not  activerecord model.
- What is the class of "form"

Thanks!

Comment: ActiveAdmin is using Formtastic to render forms, you might want to refer to the docs, or easier way is to render a partial then use default Rails form or any that you're familiar with.